# Swift use Small Caps

Tags: ios, swift, typography, xcode11.4

How can I use small caps in Swift 5 (Storyboard) / Xcode 11?

[Here's what I'm trying to accomplish.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ri9Dl.png)

I figured out how to do it in SwiftUI:

```
Text("Typography")
    .font(Font.system(.body).smallCaps())
```

But don’t now how to do it within a Storyboard-App.

This is my code so far:

```
labelBrand.font = UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 14, weight: UIFont.Weight.bold)
labelPorsche.font = UIFont.monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: UIFont.Weight.regular)
```

Thanks for your Help.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to get a *font descriptor* for the system font that you want (let’s call it `desc`), and apply the small caps as a feature:

```
let d = [
    UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.featureIdentifier: kLowerCaseType,
    UIFontDescriptor.FeatureKey.typeIdentifier: kLowerCaseSmallCapsSelector
]
let desc2 = desc.addingAttributes([.featureSettings:[d]])
```

Now translate the resulting font descriptor `desc2` back to a UIFont.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @matt. Unfortunately I don't understand how to implement your code. I got this two errors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LqoOu.png